# Automatizar collapse com BD

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, collapse

Estou fazendo um sistema para automatizar o collapse com meu mysql.

Possuo uma tabela indicada abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este sistema de collapse, funciona dentro de uma janela modal, onde tentei fazer com que apareça cada pergunta em um collapse. Para isso realizei o seguinte sistema em jquery:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

$('#minhas_duvidas').click(function() {
  var codigoVideo = $("#conteudo").val();
  var nomecomp = $("#nomecomp").val();

      $.post("buscar_duvida.php",
  {
    codigo_video: codigoVideo, nome_comp: nomecomp,
  },

  function(data, status){

    if(status == "success"){
    let itens       = '';
    let indicadores = '';

    if (duvidas.length > 0) {

            videos_pendentes.forEach(function(video, indice) {
            indicadores += 'div class="card"';

            itens += '<div class="card-header" id="headingOne">';
            itens += '<button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">'+ assunto +'</button>   ' 
            itens += '</div>';

            itens += '<div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">';
            itens += '<div class="card-body">' + pergunta;
            itens += '</div>';

        });
          $('#accordion').show();
      } else {

           alert('Nenhum vídeo pendente');
      }
     }
 });
 $('.collapse').collapse();
  });
```

Primeiramente, ele busca todas as duvidas que possuem o id do select "conteudo", ou seja ali onde existe no BD link_video_selecionado, é o valor do select que precisa buscar;

Logo após fiz um function para exibir todos as perguntas que foram mostradas no banco de dados;

Porém esse sistema não funciona e não consigo achar o motivo. O meu modal encontra-se abaixo:

```
          <div class="modal fade" id="modalQuestoes" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title">Suas questões</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            <div id="accordion">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                    <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">Collapsible Group Item #1</button>   
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    Anim parie VHS.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Voltar</button>
            </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a fazer o sistema funcionar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, Matheus!

achei a linha abaixo estranha, no seu código JS. Verifique se ajustando a abertura e fechamento da tag `div`, seu código funciona normalmente.

```js
indicadores += 'div class="card"'; // Deveria ser: indicadores += '<div class="card">';
```